# IE 10 Css Not Loading

Tags: internet-explorer-10

We are testing one of our sites on Windows 8 CTP and IE10, strangely the login page is all styled fine and looks just as IE9/chrome/etc but when I login the site is completely unstyled and the url seems to have a lot of random text in and when I view source it looks like this:

```
/)f)jfdsjfhjds8fysd893-fdsjnfjfd78df98732489324nf...
etc...
etc...
etc.../content/themes/somecss.css
```

For every referneced file/path which is the text that has been put into the url. I am assuming this is what is breaking the css although having said that despite being unstyled site navigation is still fine with this in the url and if I view source and copy and paste this in I can see the css.

Has anyone else had this?

Many thanks for any help

Edit:

This was the problem:

[IE10 User-Agent causes ASP.Net to not send back Set-Cookie (IE10 not setting cookies)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983732/ie10-user-agent-causes-asp-net-to-not-send-back-set-cookie-ie10-not-setting-coo)

Comment: If I remove the injected characters it goes back to the login page.

Comment: Also we are running this in Oracle VM VirtualBox

Comment: This was the problem:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983732/ie10-user-agent-causes-asp-net-to-not-send-back-set-cookie-ie10-not-setting-coo

Comment: This was the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983732/ie10-user-agent-causes-asp-net-to-not-send-back-set-cookie-ie10-not-setting-coo