# IE 10 Redirect URL Is Broken

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

I work on a website that works fine in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, and IE < 10. But in IE 10 on Win 8, after logging in, I get redirected to:

`https://domain.com/(F(HWiLasqNvX0ANW4jLyE6n7Ey3U_mOFxXksL-oU95Z-wf3xQ-FGD8_szv-cuhNpoDD8cKM3SBX_PCipYO1ivV03YpPzouc8wJTe6Y2JAsUdyv_Nf76LLu0dlzcsRVSGJF0))/path/`

When in all other browsers I get:

`https://domain.com/path/`

Why does IE insert that giant frackin string in the URL? More details:

- The site an ASP.NET MVC 4 site
- Hosted in IIS 7.5
- Hosted on Windows Server 2008
- Using forms authentication
- After login screen, am redirecting to the above location.

Comment: Do you have cookies enabled on IE10? At very first sight seems to be related to cookieless session management.

Comment: Do you have FormsAuth set up in `cookieless` mode?

Comment: I just have the default settings.... Looking into it further....

Comment: Reading up a bit on the cookieless business and yes, that apears to be the source of the problem. Now to figure out why IE 10 is the oddball.

Comment: Lots of good info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983732/ie10-user-agent-causes-asp-net-to-not-send-back-set-cookie-ie10-not-setting-coo

This is an old, yet active bug.

Answer (score 1):

Apply the [Hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600088)

> By default, ASP.NET uses sniffing technology for the user agent string
>   to detect browsers. The browser definition files cover a certain range
>   of browser versions. However, as the version numbers increase, ASP.NET
>   might not recognize new versions of a browser by using the user agent
>   string. In this case, ASP.NET might handle these versions as an
>   unknown browser. For example, ASP.NET cannot recognize Windows
>   Internet Explorer 10 that has the following user agent string:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/6.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

look likes it is problem with user agent detection. This issue is well described by SCOTT HANSELMAN.  http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx