# Internet explorer shows parent action method name and query string paramerter in url while action redirected to another action method

Tags: c#, jquery

> Hi, i'm working MVC4,c# web application i done some code to direct one action method to another action method "the purpose is here to hide the parent url from client" it's works fine in Chrome,Firefox but in IE10 the URL shows parent action method name and query string instead of chile action method name

```
 public ActionResult WebDocumentViewer(int caseId, string fileId)
    {
        TempData["FileId"] = fileId;
        TempData["CaseId"] = caseId;
        return RedirectToAction("Viewer");
    }
  public ActionResult Viewer()
    {
        ViewBag.fileId = TempData["FileId"];
        ViewBag.caseId = TempData["CaseId"];
        return View("ReportReview/WebDocumentViewer");
    }
```

this is my code my expected answer is: the url should display the redirected action method name("Viewer") in browser it's fine in chrome,firefox but in IE url displays redirecting action method name("WebDocumentViewer") how can i change the code to display redirected action method name in URL

my jquery Code Is:

```
 if (fileId != null && fileId != '' && fileId != 0) {
    var url = urlContext + "WebFileViewer/WebDocumentViewer?fileId=" + encodeURIComponent(fileId) + "&caseId=" + caseId;
    window.open(url, "_blank", "toolbar=no, scrollbars=yes,location=no,resizable=yes,top=100, left=250, width='" + screen.width + "', height='" + screen.height + "'");
}
else {
    alertDialogOk($('#dialog'), $('#DialogMessage'), "Error Occured View File ");
}
```

Comment: Could this be down to ASP mis-detecting IE10? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12586415/ie-10-redirect-url-is-broken

Comment: it's a problem of IE10 or asp? i'm using mvc4

Comment: It is (was?) a problem with asp.net, and mvc4 is a framework that is built on asp.net

Comment: then it's blocked way? i can't able to solve this problem it's correct?

Comment: try the hotfix: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600088 - if that doesn't fix it, then that wasn't the problem.

Comment: thanks, i hope that will help me