# Styles are not set in IE10

Tags: asp.net, .net, internet-explorer

I have two servers... one is of the TEST. Other.. of the live (productions). Both is of SAME OS and with the same hardware (32 bits), and same .NETs (4).

In one the LIVE, my styles attributes... uninclused.

**Example:**

```
<asp:textbox runat=server width=250 id=ctl32 />
```

In ALL browser, but the #10, render becomes:

```
style="width:250px;"
```

BUT in the ie10, doesn't set the style, is this a bug of .NET?

Comment: So are you saying that in PRODUCTION using Internet Explorer 10 that you do not see your `style="width:250px;"` included, but in TEST using Internet Explorer 10 that you do?

Comment: @Karl this is PROBLEM for. yes. #10... style uninclused on PRORDUCTION but, on the TEST.  also i am appologize of bad internet english.. no helps, from friend of englishs.

Comment: Maybe you need to update the browser capabilities file : http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14025964/force-asp-net-to-generate-javascript-for-all-user-agents/14026294#14026294

Answer (score 1):

first you should avoid doing inline style settings. But I think you are setting an attribute, which is a deprecated way to apply the width to an element, it should be in a style rule. So in your css file (please avoid inline styles) create a class to set your with:

.myInput250{
   width:250px;
}

and in your webforms textbox declaration reference it:

Comment: thank u but, of many codes. i am want change but, inable for other porgrammar

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an issue with the `width` attribute of an ASP.NET `TextBox` being recognized properly by Internet Explorer 10. Instead of using the `Width` attribute, try this:

```
 <asp:textbox runat="server" id="ctl32" style="width: 250px;" />
```

Comment: on asp.net you can set the `width="250"` on a asp:textbox and convert it to style.

Comment: Why is this an issue with a browser? I thought ASP.NET code was compiled to plain HTML before it hit the browser, so why is this problem occurring with the browser?

Comment: sirs, i am not ablity for making new sources. many codes. TEST in the IE #10... WIDTH inclused, live--- uninclused. same nets (4) and bits of 32.

Comment: @series0ne - this is a browser issue because of how different browsers interpret the `INPUT` tag, specifically the `size` attribute, that the ASP.NET `TextBox` gets rendered as in plain HTML.