# IE 11 has worse ASP.Net AJAX Toolkit support?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, internet-explorer-11

Why doesn't Update panel and all other controls of AJAX Toolkit 4.0 work? Everything was working till IE11 and soon when updated to IE11 got this error. It still works if set compatibility mode on. The error is;

```
if (typeof(Sys) === 'undefined') throw new Error('ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework   failed to load.');
```

Comment: Probably you have felt on the issue that did not recognize IE11, and did not know that support javascript and for that reason is not render the javascript part - check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14025964/force-asp-net-to-generate-javascript-for-all-user-agents/14026294#14026294

Comment: Finally I fixed all these IE11 issues after downloading a hotfix from microsoft and install it.
http://deepasp.wordpress.com/2013/11/27/could-not-complete-the-operation-due-to-error-80020101-in-ie11/