# ASP.Net application renders differently in IIS Servers

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, iis, webkit

I have deployed a ASP.Net web application in my server on IIS 7.5. It is rendering properly in Firefox and Chrome but not rendering properly in IE 10 or IE 11. When I deployed the same application on my Laptop (development system) IIS Server, it renders properly on IE, Firefox, Chrome and on WebkitBrowser control. So my requirement is to render in WebkitBrowser control I used in a desktop application Form. It is also not rendering properly in WebkitBrowser control.
I tried with

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
```

but failed. 
I add dword with

```
UA-Compatible IE=8, IE=9, IE=10
```

etc but still out of luck. 
It is working on my laptop but not working on deployment server. I need to render it on WebkitBrowser control. My grdarea.css class is:

```
.grdarea
{
    float: none;
/*height: 30px;*/
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 0px;
margin: 0 0 0px;
padding: 2px 0;
text-transform: uppercase;
border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
border: #0e2a3f solid 1px;
 color: #FFFFFF;
box-shadow: 0 0 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
background: #4d73a0;
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4d73a0 0%, #36639c 3%, #34619a 7%, #3060a0 10%, #2c5c9a 20%, #2d588b 30%, #284f86 47%, #234573 67%, #1b3a68 90%, #1d3c6a 93%, #1c3959 97%, #1d3a5a 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #4d73a0), color-stop(3%, #36639c), color-stop(7%, #34619a), color-stop(10%, #3060a0), color-stop(20%, #2c5c9a), color-stop(30%, #2d588b), color-stop(47%, #284f86), color-stop(67%, #234573), color-stop(90%, #1b3a68), color-stop(93%, #1d3c6a), color-stop(97%, #1c3959), color-stop(100%, #1d3a5a));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4d73a0 0%, #36639c 3%, #34619a 7%, #3060a0 10%, #2c5c9a 20%, #2d588b 30%, #284f86 47%, #234573 67%, #1b3a68 90%, #1d3c6a 93%, #1c3959 97%, #1d3a5a 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #4d73a0 0%, #36639c 3%, #34619a 7%, #3060a0 10%, #2c5c9a 20%, #2d588b 30%, #284f86 47%, #234573 67%, #1b3a68 90%, #1d3c6a 93%, #1c3959 97%, #1d3a5a 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #4d73a0 0%, #36639c 3%, #34619a 7%, #3060a0 10%, #2c5c9a 20%, #2d588b 30%, #284f86 47%, #234573 67%, #1b3a68 90%, #1d3c6a 93%, #1c3959 97%, #1d3a5a 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #4d73a0 0%, #36639c 3%, #34619a 7%, #3060a0 10%, #2c5c9a 20%, #2d588b 30%, #284f86 47%, #234573 67%, #1b3a68 90%, #1d3c6a 93%, #1c3959 97%, #1d3a5a 100%);
```

}

```
.grdarea:hover
{

background: #45484d;
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA 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);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #45484d 0%, #000 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #45484d), color-stop(100%, #000));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #45484d 0%, #000 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #45484d 0%, #000 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #45484d 0%, #000 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #45484d 0%, #000 100%);
```

}

```
One of my Page Source Code: 

<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="FrmUserLogin.aspx.cs"  Inherits="VisionWebPortal.FrmUserLogin" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit"  Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"  TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
<%@ Register Src="MessageBoxUsc/uscMsgBox.ascx" TagName="uscMsgBox" TagPrefix="uc1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<meta content="IE=edge,chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<title>Vision Web Tv</title>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.main.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.movingboxes.js"></script>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="css/ie.css"  type="text/css"/><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE]><script type="text/javascript" src="js/ie.js"></script><![endif]-->
<style>
.CentereObj1 {float:left;width:50%; height :400px; margin-left:10px; margin-right:auto; margin-top :30px; }
.tbl
{
 width:50%; border-collapse: collapse; margin-top:85px;margin-left:20px;
}
 .tbl td{border: none
         } 
.tbl th{border: none} 
.col 
 {
 }
 .topMargin{ margin-top:50px;}
.TextBoxes{margin:20px 0 20px 0;    }
.LeftF{ float :left ;}
.CenterF { margin:0 auto;}   
</style>
</head>
<body >
<div id="wrapper">
<header id="header">
<h1 class="logo"><a href="#"></a></h1>
<div class="header-holder"></div>
</header> 
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<AjaxControls:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" EnableScriptGlobalization="true"
    EnableScriptLocalization="true">
</AjaxControls:ToolkitScriptManager>
   <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
<table class ="tbl" >
     <tr>
             <td colspan="3">
                          </td>
             <td colspan="3">

             </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td  colspan="6">
                 &nbsp;
                 <div class ="LeftF">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="SIGN IN       " 
                                Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Larger" Font-Underline="True"></asp:Label>
                                <asp:Label
                                    ID="Label4" runat="server" 
                                Text="                Welcome to Vision Web TV!" Font-Bold="True" 
                                Font-Underline="False"></asp:Label>
                             </div> 
                 </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td class="style5">
                 <div class ="LeftF">
                 <asp:TextBox ID="username" runat="server" Height="25px" Width="250px"></asp:TextBox>
                 <ajaxToolkit:RoundedCornersExtender ID="rce" runat="server" Corners="All" 
                     Radius="15" TargetControlID="username" />
                     </div> 
                                  </td>
             <td class="style7">
              <div class ="LeftF">
                 <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRememberMe" runat="server" Text="Remember Password?" 
                      TabIndex="3" />
                 </div>
             </td>
             <td class="style2" colspan="2">
                 &nbsp;</td>
             <td class="style2">
                 <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
             </td>
             <td class="style1">
                 &nbsp;</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td class="style5">
              <div class ="LeftF">
                 <asp:TextBox ID="passwd" runat="server" Height="25px" TextMode="Password" 
                     Width="250px" TabIndex="1"></asp:TextBox>
             <ajaxToolkit:RoundedCornersExtender ID="RoundedCornersExtender2" runat="server"
TargetControlID="passwd"
Radius="15"
Corners="All" />
            </div>

             </td>
             <td class="style7">
                 <div class="LeftF">
                     <a href="#">Forgot your password </a>
                 </div>
             </td>
             <td class="style2" colspan="2">
                 &nbsp;</td>
             <td class="style2">
                 &nbsp;</td>
             <td class="style1">
                 &nbsp;</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td class="style5">
              <div class ="LeftF">
                 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" BackColor="#999999" CssClass="grdarea" 
                     Font-Size="Large" ForeColor="Black" Height="30px" onclick="Button1_Click" 
                     Text="GO!" Width="250px" TabIndex="2" />
                     </div> 
             </td>
             <td class="style7">
                 &nbsp;</td>
             <td class="style2" colspan="2">
                 &nbsp;</td>
             <td class="style2">
                 &nbsp;</td>
             <td class="style1">
                 &nbsp;</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td class="style5">
                 <div class="LeftF">
                     <a href="FrmUserRegis.aspx">New User Register Here</a>
                 </div>
             </td>
             <td class="style7">
                 &nbsp;</td>
             <td class="style2" colspan="2">
                 &nbsp;</td>
             <td class="style2">
                 &nbsp;</td>
             <td class="style1">
                 &nbsp;</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td class="style5" colspan="6">

                 <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" BackColor="#990000"   Font-Bold="False" 
                     Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="White" 
                     Text="System Message| Can be viewed best in 1024x768 resolution, for any query please call at 111-000-222.                                                         " 
                     Width="100%"></asp:Label>

             </br>
             </td>
         </tr>
     </table>
            </div>   
        </div>  
     </ContentTemplate>
       <Triggers>
   <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" />
    </Triggers> 

            </asp:UpdatePanel>
       <uc1:uscMsgBox ID="uscMsgBox1" runat="server" />
    </form>
</div>        
</body>
</html>
```

The Button1 in this case is not rendered properly in IE while renders ok in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Intranet, compatibility mode. Try the search with those keywords. [Override intranet compatibility mode IE8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518256/override-intranet-compatibility-mode-ie8) for example.

Comment: Maybe the browser definitions are not up to date for ie10 and ie11. Look also : http://stackoverflow.com/a/14026294/159270

Comment: Still no luck.. @CodeCaster

Comment: Still struggling to find the solution @Aristos

Comment: Can you clarify a couple of things a) is it the same PC and IE 10/11 installation that you using to compare dev and prod? b) what part of the page is not rendering correctly (link or code would be good)?

Comment: The deployment on a laptop I used for development of application is rendering properly very well on all browsers including IE and WebkitBrowser control. I mean when I host it on my laptop IIS services, then it works fine but is not working on other PC or servers. The alignment and elements are not rendering properly. The link of application is: http://interactive.on-the-web.tv:8066/. So you can check the "GO!" button on IE Chrome and Firefox. It can renders properly on Chrome and Firefox but not on IE. @steve

Comment: Lets look at the Go! button. IE gives me the following: `<input type="submit" name="Button1" value="GO!" id="Button1" tabindex="2" class="grdarea" />` Chrome gives me: `<input type="submit" name="Button1" value="GO!" id="Button1" tabindex="2" class="grdarea" style="color:Black;background-color:#999999;font-size:Large;height:30px;width:250px;" />` Pls post the source/ASP code for this part of the page.

Comment: Do I need to edit the Question by placing grdarea css class code? It is too long to place in comment. steve

Comment: yes - please edit the question and post code. I'm curious why chome would show a style applied, but not IE. Are you using jQuery?

Comment: Also please post the resulting output from the IE debugger when you run it against your local server (the one that formats correctly).

Comment: @ZahidKakar: can you please check if the version of IIS used in laptop and in the server are the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the same IE installation works for your local server, but not for the production one, I'm thinking that this is most likely a deployment issue.

Some typical problems with a production IIS configuration could be:

1. It is missing some files
2. It is missing some authorisation on those files (ie. you have a web.config that doesn't authorise anonymous users to download) - check prod vs. test web.configs authorisation/authentication sections
3. Your Windows IIS app pool login doesn't have file-level read access to some of the files in your deployment (check file properties, security for all the files on your deployment)
4. It is missing some file extensions

If its the format that is screwed, most likely the missing file is a `.css` or `.js` file.

One way to track this down is via the browser tools (F12). You can open the 'network tab' and start tracing, then open the page. If you start to see HTTP 4xx or 5xx errors for some of the linked files, most likely it's one of the issues above.

Comment: I used F12 debugger but has no error message. I compared IIS versions and OS on both both machines are same. I edited the question and pasted some source code for you.

Comment: Secondly the Production Server application can render properly on Chrome and Firefox but no luck in IE. This means no file is missing.

Comment: Actually it doesn't, you have a lot of "if IE" checks in there, then loading ie.css and ie.js. I would start by making sure those files are in the proper directories. If this is accessible on the Internet, possibly you could post a link for us to look at?

Answer (score 0):

Had some strage problems with IE 10,11 on pages containing ajaxControlToolkit controls. solved it by adding ie.browser file to the App_Browsers folder of my asp.net application with the following content:

```
<browsers>
    <!-- Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4325) -->
    <browser id="IE6Plus" parentID="IE">
        <identification>
            <capability name="majorversion" match="^[6-9]|\d{2,}$" />
        </identification>

        <capabilities>
            <capability name="ecmascriptversion"    value="3.0" />
            <capability name="jscriptversion"       value="5.6" />
            <capability name="javascript"           value="true" />
            <capability name="javascriptversion"    value="1.5" />
            <capability name="msdomversion"         value="${majorversion}.${minorversion}" />
            <capability name="w3cdomversion"        value="1.0" />
            <capability name="ExchangeOmaSupported" value="true" />
            <capability name="activexcontrols"      value="true" />
            <capability name="backgroundsounds"     value="true" />
            <capability name="cookies"              value="true" />
            <capability name="frames"               value="true" />
            <capability name="javaapplets"          value="true" />
            <capability name="supportsCallback"     value="true" />
            <capability name="supportsFileUpload"   value="true" />
            <capability name="supportsMultilineTextBoxDisplay" value="true" />
            <capability name="supportsMaintainScrollPositionOnPostback" value="true" />
            <capability name="supportsVCard"        value="true" />
            <capability name="supportsXmlHttp"      value="true" />
            <capability name="tables"               value="true" />
            <capability name="supportsAccessKeyAttribute"    value="true" />
            <capability name="tagwriter"            value="System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter" />
            <capability name="vbscript"             value="true" />
        </capabilities>
    </browser>

    <!-- Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0;) -->
    <browser id="IE6to9" parentID="IE6Plus">
      <identification>
        <capability name="majorversion" match="^[6-9]$" />
      </identification>
    </browser>

    <!-- Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0;) -->
    <browser id="IE7" parentID="IE6to9">
        <identification>
            <capability name="majorversion" match="^7$" />
        </identification>
        <capabilities>
            <capability name="jscriptversion" value="5.7" />
        </capabilities>
    </browser>

    <!-- Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729) -->
    <browser id="IE8" parentID="IE6to9">
        <identification>
            <capability name="majorversion" match="^8$" />
        </identification>
        <capabilities>
            <capability name="jscriptversion" value="6.0" />
        </capabilities>
    </browser>

  <!-- Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729) -->
  <browser id="IE9" parentID="IE6to9">
    <identification>
      <capability name="majorversion" match="^9$" />
    </identification>
    <capabilities>
      <capability name="jscriptversion" value="6.0" />
    </capabilities>
  </browser>

  <!-- Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0) -->
  <browser id="IE10Plus" parentID="IE6Plus">
    <identification>
      <capability name="majorversion" match="\d{2,}" />
    </identification>
    <capabilities>
      <capability name="jscriptversion" value="6.0" />
    </capabilities>
  </browser>

  <browser id="IE11" parentID="Mozilla">
    <identification>
      <userAgent match="Trident/(?'layoutVersion'[7-9]|0*[1-9]\d+)(\.\d+)?;(.*;)?\s*rv:(?'version'(?'major'\d+)(\.(?'minor'\d+)))" />
      <userAgent nonMatch="IEMobile" />
    </identification>
    <capture>
      <userAgent match="Trident/(?'layoutVersion'\d+)" />
    </capture>
    <capabilities>
      <capability name="browser"              value="IE" />
      <capability name="layoutEngine"         value="Trident" />
      <capability name="layoutEngineVersion"  value="${layoutVersion}" />
      <capability name="extra"                value="${extra}" />
      <capability name="isColor"              value="true" />
      <capability name="letters"              value="${letters}" />
      <capability name="majorversion"         value="${major}" />
      <capability name="minorversion"         value="${minor}" />
      <capability name="screenBitDepth"       value="8" />
      <capability name="type"                 value="IE${major}" />
      <capability name="version"              value="${version}" />
    </capabilities>
  </browser>

  <!-- Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11,0) like Gecko -->
  <browser id="IE110" parentID="IE11">
    <identification>
      <capability name="majorversion" match="11" />
    </identification>

    <capabilities>
      <capability name="ecmascriptversion"    value="3.0" />
      <capability name="jscriptversion"       value="5.6" />
      <capability name="javascript"           value="true" />
      <capability name="javascriptversion"    value="1.5" />
      <capability name="msdomversion"         value="${majorversion}.${minorversion}" />
      <capability name="w3cdomversion"        value="1.0" />
      <capability name="ExchangeOmaSupported" value="true" />
      <capability name="activexcontrols"      value="true" />
      <capability name="backgroundsounds"     value="true" />
      <capability name="cookies"              value="true" />
      <capability name="frames"               value="true" />
      <capability name="javaapplets"          value="true" />
      <capability name="supportsCallback"     value="true" />
      <capability name="supportsFileUpload"   value="true" />
      <capability name="supportsMultilineTextBoxDisplay" value="true" />
      <capability name="supportsMaintainScrollPositionOnPostback" value="true" />
      <capability name="supportsVCard"        value="true" />
      <capability name="supportsXmlHttp"      value="true" />
      <capability name="tables"               value="true" />
      <capability name="supportsAccessKeyAttribute"    value="true" />
      <capability name="tagwriter"            value="System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter" />
      <capability name="vbscript"             value="true" />
    </capabilities>
  </browser>

  <gateway id="IEbeta" parentID="IE">
        <identification>
            <capability name="letters" match="^([bB]|ab)" />
        </identification>

        <capture>
        </capture>

        <capabilities>
            <capability name="beta"    value="true" />
        </capabilities>
    </gateway>
</browsers>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Add this line of code to _Layout.cshtml

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```