# HTTP 500 Internal Server Error in IE

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-9, iis-7.5

I am getting "HTTP 500 Internal Server Error" in IE9 and the earlier versions of IE in one of the page of my ASP.net application. In all other browsers and newer versions of IE, it's working fine.

If I uncheck "Show friendly HTTP error messages" from the advance option of IE then it's working.But it's not a solution. :)

Is there any way to fix this ?

Please advise.

Comment: HTTP/500 should be a response from your server side. Are you checking something in your ASP program that isn't SET for old IE and you didn't handle exceptions?

Comment: First you start from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385714/deploying-website-500-internal-server-error/5385884#5385884

Comment: Second, you check that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14025964/force-asp-net-to-generate-javascript-for-all-user-agents/14026294#14026294

Comment: Ken Cheung, Ya I cross verified all the java scripts and CSS which might affect the older IE versions. But I am not able to find anything wrong. I am also not able to get any error message too. Is there any way to get correct error message on this situation, so I can investigate more ?

Comment: @Aristos , thanks for providing these links... I have tried with this but getting the same result. If I can get real error then I can do something to fix this.Do u have any idea to find the cause of this issue ??

Comment: @KenCheung , Please put a light on this if  you have any idea..

Comment: Check the second link and understand that the asp.net is return diferent thinks depends from the browser, so you need to update that files that mentioned on the second link

Comment: You're talking about HTTP/500, which means your server side code has problem, throws exception, and make IIS to give out the Internal Server Error response instead of a HTTP/200 with HTML. It's not JavaScript or CSS issue. Check your server side ASP.net program!

Comment: Try follow this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8z01xdh.aspx to enable debugging, and browse it with IE9 that originally throw HTTP/500, and update us what you can see.