# IE 10 Login Issues

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-mvc-2, internet-explorer-10

On win 7 and win 8, my login has stopped working in IE 10 only. The rest of the browsers are behaving normal. IE 9 on win 7 is working ok also.

This is what we have on the mvc section of the site. The ajax confirmation goes back to  the page and it then redirects to the dashboard page. Since dashboard page is behind login, the user gets redirected back to the login page.

```
public void SignInUser(UserInfo user)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            SessionService.AbandonSession();
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.UserId, false);
            //here we put the user in session
            //here we log hit
        }
```

and this is what we have on the Kentico CMS side, classic asp.net. Here it is a webservice request, login code executes and then confirmation gets back to the page which in turn redirects to the dashboard page. The same thing happens here too. User gets redirected back to the login page.

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.UserId, false);
```

Has any one else seen such behavior om their website?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a [hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600088?wa=wsignin1.0) for this issue, in which a [Set-Cookie header is not sent back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983732/ie10-user-agent-causes-asp-net-to-not-send-back-set-cookie-ie10-not-setting-coo) when using IE 10.

This is also on [Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/662275/asp-net-user-agent-sniffing-and-ie10-internet-explorer-10) and if you cannot apply the hotfix, a workaround has been mentioned in the connect thread.

Answer (score 1):

Simply install `.net framework 4.5`, It will fix most of your issues that you are facing in `IE10 & IE11`. `.net framework 4.5` is highly compatible with `framework 4.0` and resolve most of the issues for `IE9, IE10 and IE11`. You don't need to target your application framework to 4.5, leave it 4.0 in build configurations.

Answer (score 0):

This issue generally arises due to cache problem for internet explorer versions.
You just need to write the following code in `Application_BeginRequest()` in `global.asax` file.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-1));
    Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
}
```