# FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie doesnot work in IE10 and IIS 6.0

Tags: asp.net, cookies, webforms, internet-explorer-10

FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie doesnot work in IIS 6.0 when I use IE10 in Windows 7.
I use Fiddler to monitor the cookie, and I found that in IIS 6.0 and IE10, it doesnot set the cookie.

Test case results:

1. When I use FireFox and IIS 6.0 it works.
2. When I use IE9 and  IIS 6.0 it works.
3. When I use IE10 compatible mode and IIS 6.0 it works.
4. When I use IE10 and IIS 7.0 it works.
5. When I use IE10 and IIS 6.0 it doesnot work.

The page code is simple:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("Demo", false);
```

Thanks.

Comment: see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983732/ie10-user-agent-causes-asp-net-to-not-send-back-set-cookie-ie10-not-setting-coo

Answer (score 0):

You auth cookie is set when your request reaches the client. Make sure you don't have any errors that could force the asp.net runtime to redirect to error page.

Also, a response.Redirect might cause issues.

Comment: The same code works in IIS7 with IE10, but doesnot work in IIS6 with IE10.

Comment: Out of ideas, sorry. Perhaps you can use Fiddler to investigate what's going on?

Comment: On my setup the difference is that IIS6 isn't sending back the .ASPXAUTH cookie on IE10. Firefox and Chrome are working fine.