# Unexpected URL in deployed asp.net MVC app

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have deployed my asp.net MVC app to production, and it works as expected.  However, when using F12 in IE to see the Network requests that are being made to the server, I see the requests being sent with this format:

```
http://172.16.10.2/VMSWebTest/(F(pZPg-rE4Nghw1pU6TbKBwuNIeLCVHnerv1BO7BG3hZlmLxqretATeKFdrZU2b9Qr_rg2-wieUwZOJ9PkcwWdRzRSP_oUEI5mdmd4vzbrqbM1))/Tiers
```

instead of this format:

```
http://172.16.10.2/VMSWebTest/Tiers
```

Where is that (F(pZPg-rE4Nghw1pU6TbKBwuNIeLCVHnerv1BO7BG3hZlmLxqretATeKFdrZU2b9Qr_rg2-wieUwZOJ9PkcwWdRzRSP_oUEI5mdmd4vzbrqbM1)) part of the URL coming from? Why? What is it's purpose?

I've noticed this only seems to be with IE, as the request url are as expected when using Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be that you are the victim of a bug where ASP.NET can not recognize IE10, please see the suggestions in this answer:
[IE10 User-Agent causes ASP.Net to not send back Set-Cookie (IE10 not setting cookies)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983732/ie10-user-agent-causes-asp-net-to-not-send-back-set-cookie-ie10-not-setting-coo)

Specifically, there is a hotfix available: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600088

Comment: I followed the workaround suggested re the BrowserFile under App_Browsers and now all is well. Freaky!