# Asp.Net MVC 4 Html ActionLink helper returns odd link for IE10.

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an Asp.Net MVC 4 application and I am using the Html ActionLink helper as follows:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Public", "ClearSearch", new { area = "PropertyListing", controller = "RealEstateTaxParcel"}, new {  @class = "access-button" })
```

In IE 9 the generated html is as follow:

```
<a class="access-button" href="/AscentWeb/PropertyListing/RealEstateTaxParcel/ClearSearch">Public</a>
```

But in IE10 the generated html is as follows:

```
<a class="access-button" href="/AscentWeb/(F(-5ahfuK90o-Rb7YpQXCTW0uuxd3WCIpfmvCNvNfA1ZE1UdhSzqavHg4Nc_hyfRbicx0idwSahX1CRI9G6p3bW5Ud6Q2OfQbq-3kduvCgbBIDEzHvWHuDgauF8qh_xiFJ0))/PropertyListing/RealEstateTaxParcel/ClearSearch">Public</a>
```

This only occurs on the website that is deployed to IIS. The link is generated just fine in IE10 when I run the site from VS2010. Any thoughts or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983732/ie10-user-agent-causes-asp-net-to-not-send-back-set-cookie-ie10-not-setting-coo and apply this hotfix: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600088.

Comment: Thanks alexn. That took care of the issue.