# Authentication cookie is not passed after login using IE10

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, cookies, form-authentication

I have an asp.net website located on some server.
I try to login the website using IE10 compatibility mode, I fill user name and password, and when I press on the "Login" button, nothing happens. I get the login page again.

I checked with wireshark and found out that the cookie is not passed when redirecting from the login page.

I tried the workarounds from this post:
[IE10 User-Agent causes ASP.Net to not send back Set-Cookie (IE10 not setting cookies)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983732/ie10-user-agent-causes-asp-net-to-not-send-back-set-cookie-ie10-not-setting-coo)

I checked that the date and time of the server are equal to the date and time of the browser, and my server name doesn't contain non alphanumeric characters.
I tried changing the browser settings, restore to default and I tried with or without compatibility mode, but nothing helps!

(in chrome everything works fine and the cookie is passed).

Does someone have an idea about that?

Comment: That part about the domain name being alpha-numeric is important - IE won't set cookies for domains with an underscore (_) in them. See Q5 [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/08/20/wininet-ie-cookie-internals-faq.aspx?PageIndex=5)

Answer (score 0):

Still cannot post comments...

You can always use `cookieless="AutoDetect"` to use Uri instead of cookies if it cannot set cookie. Some user may even deny all cookies, that is why all advertisements use only Uri mode.
Though it might result in share of Uri (easier than to share cookies) and if a user shouldn't be allowed to login from different places at once you'll need to revise your login logic.